# Temperature of my laptop

Tags: dell, inspiron, temperature

I am using Dell Inspiron-3521 and it's temperatures rises when I am watching anything on youtube or netflix. I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Has this always been the case and are you sure that your computer fan is working properly?

Comment: or that your vents are not clogged with dust?

Comment: I recently installed ubuntu 15.10. My fan speed stays high even when I am not using.